# How to use Oracle Type like in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, plsql

I'm now working with SQLServer 2012 and my background is Oracle.
Right now i'm developing some procedures and i wondering if there is something like table types like in PL/SQL.

For instance, in PL/SQL i do something like this

```
Type X is table of ( 
field_1 varchar2(100), 
field_2 varchar2(100)) index by pls_integer
```

Is there something like this in T-SQL ?!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server certainly supports user defined types (UDTs). Eg. see [`create type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx).

However, despite many years of standards existing, every vendor's SQL is somewhat different, you just have to learn the differences. Eg. in T-SQL it is just `varchar`.

Comment: Thanks @Richard for the awnser. That is a simple example what i want to achive in TSQL. I know that varchar2 is something by oracle. I need some dinamic type, not a type the stays in Database, only declared in Procedure. It's possible? Thanks in Advnce

Comment: @AndréFonseca Yes, [table valued variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) or temporary tables (latter is `create table #name…`). Hint: get used to navigating the MSDN docs, like the Oracle docs everything is there somewhere.